# imagesLoaded method not working with JQuery masonry and infinite scroll

Tags: image, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll, loaded

I've been using JQuery masonry and now I'm adding infinite scroll. There are images in nearly every masonry "brick" and before I was using infinite scroll the images loaded fine and everything was great. I added the next part of the javascript for the infinite scroll and added the imagesLoaded method inside but when the new bricks are appended they come out all piled on top. My assumption is that I am not adding the imagesLoaded method properly in the infinite scroll callback but I haven't been able to find my error. Here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.tile',
            columnWidth : 240
          });
        });


    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : ".flickr_pagination",            
                       // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        nextSelector : "a.next_page",    
                       // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : "div.tile"          
                       // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );

        $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            masonry( 'appended', $newElems );
        });
      }
    );
    });
</script>
```

The first JQuery masonry call works fine and hasn't been touched. It's the second part where there seems to be a problem. Thanks for the help and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: An additional observation is that when I scroll to the bottom I actually see the pagination controls for an instant before they disappear. Also, I'm using the will_paginate gem in a Sinatra app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the answer

```
$(function(){

        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.tile',
            columnWidth : 240
          });
        });

    $container.infinitescroll({
          navSelector  : '.flickr_pagination',    // selector for the paged navigation 
          nextSelector : 'a.next_page',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
          itemSelector : '.tile',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
          loading: {
              finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
              img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
            }
          },
          // trigger Masonry as a callback
          function( newElements ) {
            // hide new items while they are loading
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
            // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
              // show elems now they're ready
              $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
              $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
            });
          }
        );
    });
```

The problem was I was calling .imagesLoaded() on $container in the infinite scroll callback function and I should have been calling it on $newElements.

Comment: I would suggest starting a new question about it, need to see your code in order to trouble shoot the problem.